# ¿cómo hago para enviar parámetros que usan un ng-click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5, xhtml

Tengo que un método que hace una llamada, me devuelve los datos que necesito, que son la descripción de unos privilegios, código (ejemplo: MS) y el valor que es true o false, el problema surge cuando quiero cambiar el estado de cada de los privilegios, no entiendo como enviar los datos que tengo en mi tabla porque al hacerlo me sale que no tan definidos.

Quiero aclarar que soy nuevo en Angularjs y no sé si parte de mi código está bien.

```
<section ng-controller="ObtenerPrivilegiosXUsuarioID">
<h1><strong>Usuario ID: {{UsuarioID}}</strong></h1>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                <h4 style="float:left">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" ng-model="q" placeholder="Filtrar" autofocus uppercase />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="q=''" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </h4>
                <h4 style="float:right">
                    <a href="javascript:history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i> Volver</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/#/inicio"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Salir</a>
                </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Descripcion</th>
            <th> Valor</th>
            <th> Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="Privilegio in Privilegios |filter:q ">
            <td align="center"><span ng-bind="Privilegio.Descripcion" ng-model="Privilegio.Descripcion"></span></td>
            <td style="display:none"><span ng-bind="Privilegio.Codigo" ng-model="Privilegio.Codigo"></span></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Privilegio.Valor" /></td>
            <td align="center">
                <button ng-disabled="Privilegio.Valor == true" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="darPrivilegio()" >Dar Privilegio</button>
                <button ng-disabled="Privilegio.Valor == false" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="quitarPrivilegio()" >Quitar Privilegio</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
    this.darPrivilegio = function (Codigo) {
        $scope.Privilegio.Codigo = Codigo;
        Consulta = {
            URL: webServiceUsuarios,
            Metodo: 'ActualizarPrivilegio',
            Parametros: {
                Token: obtenerToken(),
                UsuarioID: $routeParams.UsuarioID,
                'Codigo':$scope.Privilegio.Codigo,
                'Valor': true,                   
            },
        };       

        WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta).then(function (response) {
            if (response.CodError == 0) {
                bootbox.alert("Se actualizaron los privilegios del Usuario ID <strong>" + $scope.UsuarioID + "</strong>", function () {
                    $route.reload();
                });
            } else {
                bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
            }
            $.skylo('end');
        });
     }

    this.quitarPrivilegio = function (Codigo) {
        $scope.Privilegio.Codigo = Codigo;
        Consulta = {
            URL: webServiceUsuarios,
            Metodo: 'ActualizarPrivilegio',
            Parametros: {
                Token: obtenerToken(),
                UsuarioID: $routeParams.UsuarioID,
                'Codigo':$scope.Privilegio.Codigo,
                'Valor': false,                   
            },
        };       

        WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta).then(function (response) {
            if (response.CodError == 0) {
                bootbox.alert("Se actualizaron los privilegios del Usuario ID <strong>" + $scope.UsuarioID + "</strong>", function () {
                    $route.reload();
                });
            } else {
                bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
            }
            $.skylo('end');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa no me aparece nada en la vista donde debe salir el resultante del codigo, por que no lo pones aqui de una vez en la pregunta

Comment: no te saldria nada alli, puse el codigo alli para mas comodidad, pero qui va

Comment: Bueno ya vi el código, soy nuevo en angular, pero igual no dices cual es el error en si, si te sale algún error, o si no te aparece nada, como si funcionara todo, pero no te lanza ningún resultado.

Comment: Actualize mi código, y puse la parte en la que necesito ayuda. quiero pasarle los parámetros de la vista en este caso lo unico que no se como pasar es `Codigo`  y no se por que, pero no me sale nada ni tampoco un error, lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el la respuesta que me da el web service, ya que me da si un valor true y yo al enviarle false esa sea la nueva respuesta

Comment: no se en que estoy fallando y tan solo ese parametro me falta enviar, despues el token, id de usuario y valor ya envia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías usar una sintaxis así, ya que los métodos esperan el parámetro Codigo

```
ng-click="darPrivilegio(Privilegio.Codigo)"
```

Por otro lado, donde pones

```
this.darPrivilegio = function (Codigo) {
```

deberías usar

```
$scope.darPrivilegio = function (Codigo) {
```

Dado que para usar `this` se usa otra sintaxis de Angular conocida como `controller as` pero como no puede combinarse con la sintaxias de controller por $scope, el método queda inaccesible para el markup.

## Actualizacion

Viendo el codigo completo, (no puedo correrlo por que no tengo la API/usuario/clave), creo que el problema viene por que `$scope.darPrivilegio` y `$scope.quitarPrivilegio` **estan definidos dentro del** `then` de `WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta)`.

Te recomiendo que muevas ambos metodos fuera del callback y que los armes de la siguiente forma: (fijate en los comentarios en el codigo)

```
// usa $scope y recibe un parametro
$socpe.darPrivilegio = function (codigo) {
    Consulta = {
        URL: webServiceUsuarios,
        Metodo: 'ActualizarPrivilegio',
        Parametros: {
            Token: obtenerToken(),
            UsuarioID: $routeParams.UsuarioID,
            'Codigo': codigo, // no uses el $scope.Privilegios aqui, usa la el parametro de la funcion.
            'Valor': true,                   
        },
    };       

    WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta).then(function (response) {
        if (response.CodError == 0) {
            bootbox.alert("Se actualizaron los privilegios del Usuario ID <strong>" + $scope.UsuarioID + "</strong>", function () {
                $route.reload();
            });
        } else {
            bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
        }
        $.skylo('end');
    });
 }
```

Luego invoca ambos pasandole el codigo que quieres usar en la solicitud WSAPP

```
<button ng-click="darPrivilegio(Privilegio.Codigo)" >Dar Privilegio</button>
<button ng-click="quitarPrivilegio(Privilegio.Codigo)" >Quitar Privilegio</button>
```

Comment: ya eh hecho eso y no me funciona, no se mas que hacer.

Comment: @SebastianKullman he editado la respuesta.

Comment: @SebastianKullman avisame como te fue, y si necesitas ayuda con esto

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: puede agregar un console.log(Codigo); como primera linea de la funcion y decirme que sale en la consola?

Comment: no sale nada, que me recomiendas?

Comment: esta accesible para ver en algun lado?

Comment: no lo tengo pero puedo enviarte el codigo

Comment: de acuerdo, subelo a alguna parte publica y me lo descargo desde ahi mismo.. no me gusta pasarte mi mail por aqui.

Comment: @SebastianKullman necesito algo de tiempo, estoy en el trabajo un poco ocupado ahora mismo. En cuanto me libero lo miro

Comment: Espero tu respuesta.

Comment: @SebastianKullman fijate en la edicion y luego me dices

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, viendo un poco tu codigo, donde esta el `ng-click`, puedo ver que no llamas una funcion, por ende no creo que puedas enviar ni ejecutar algo asociado a ese boton.

En tal caso lo correcto para que ng-click llame un funcion y ejecute algun evento que tengas programado seria asi:

```
<button ng-click="nombreControlador()">Ejecutar</button>
```

Y en el fichero javascript seria algo así:

```
angular.module('nombreApp', ['dependencias'])
       .controller('nombreControlador', nombreControlador);

nombreControlador.$inject = ['dependencias'];

function nombreControlador(dependencia) {

  //procesos a ejecutarse
}
```

Comment: no creo que eso funcione, debería ser un método del controlador no el controlador en si .

Comment: edite mi codigo, funciona a medias pero aun me falta enviar un parametro que es `Codigo` el cual no se como enviar

Comment: @SebastianKullman mira la respuesta que te dio abajo rnd

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales ya eh hecho eso y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @SebastianKullman podrias poner el error que te aparece

Comment: no me aparece ningun error, nada

Comment: @SebastianKullman sabes como correr tu aplicacion o pagina web o lo que sea pero poniendo puntos de interrupcion para saber que esta pasando en cada proceso o en los que tu desee, si sabes usalo, si no te recomiendo aplicarlo igual